# Parallel Write Operations in GraphDB Free vs. Standard Edition

Tags: graphdb

I am trying to run several SPARQL queries in parallel in Ontotext GraphDB. These queries are identical except for the named graph which they read from. I've attempted a multithreading solution in Scala to launch 3 queries against the database in parallel (see picture below).

The issue is that I am using the Free Edition of GraphDB, which only supports a single core for write operations. What this seems to mean is that the queries which are supposed to run in parallel basically just queue up to run against the single core. As you can see, the first query has completed 41,145 operations in 12 seconds, but no operations have completed on the two other queries. Once the first query completes, the second query will run to completion, and once that completes, the third will run.

I understand this is likely expected behavior for the Free Edition. My question is, will upgrading to the Standard Edition fix this problem and allow the queries to actually run in parallel? Based on the documentation I've looked at, it seems that multiple cores can be made available for the Standard Edition to complete write operations. However, I also saw something which implied that single write queries launched against the Standard Edition would automatically be processed over multiple cores, which might make the multithreading approach obsolete anyway?

Anyone have experience with launching parallel write operations against GraphDB and is able to weigh in?

[image: Screenshot of running 3 queries in parallel]

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference in the official GraphDB 9.1 benchmark statistics page:
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/benchmark.html.